# boto3 delete_object after get_object leads to : botocore.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: Read timeout on endpoint URL:

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm in the process of implementing a new functionality that will rely on s3 buckets and I have a really strange problem.

So, we will have 2 buckets for files downloaded from internet. 1st bucket will basically store all kinds of files that we will find. Later on I wan't copy all files that ['ContentType'] == 'text/plain' to final/destination bucket and remove all the files that ['ContentType'] != 'text/plain' from 1st bucket.

To achieve the intended effect I use **get_object** with **delete_object**.

```
    object_get_response = self.client.get_object(
        Bucket=self.bucket_name,
        Key=HARDCODED_PATH
    )
    if object_get_response['ContentType'] != 'text/plain':
        response = self.client.delete_object(
            Bucket=self.bucket_name,
            Key=HARDCODED_PATH,
        )
```

Unfortunately, for some reason unknown to me, the process ends with an error when calling **delete_object**. I receive response from **get_object** without any issues.

**botocore.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: Read timeout on endpoint URL**

The most interesting thing is that the problem only appears after calling get_object first.
If I just call **delete_object**, everything works and the file will be deleted.

I would be very grateful for any suggestions and comments. I'm already frustrated ;)

Comment: Are you using a VPC endpoint to S3? What is in the associated [endpoint policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpc-endpoints-access.html)?

Comment: Right now I testing this code locally with local minio buckets.

Comment: Could be a latency problem ? Have you tried increasing timeout settings ? Anything interesting on the AWS Service Health Dashboard?